# Create a function that strips the $, converts to float and apply to pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, function, pandas-groupby

I created a function that strips the '$' in the number and converts it to float then add the total sum in the column. And when I tried calling that function to the groupby, I am getting an error. Here's the code:

```
def total_sales():
    return df['Total sales USD'].str.strip('$').astype(float).sum()

df_order_sales_date = df.groupby(['column1','column2']).apply(total_sales)
```

Im getting an error that says 'TypeError: total_sales() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given'

What should I do? Is it possible to create a function that strips the $, converts the string to float and add the total then apply it to the columns in groupby? Thanks for the help

Comment: In this situation, I wouldn't use a custom function. I would just write two separate lines of code like this:

    `df['Total sales USD'] = df['Total sales USD'].str.strip('$').astype(float)`
    `df_order_sales_date = df.groupby(['column1','column2'])['Total sales USD'].sum()`

Comment: It worked. Thanks David!

Comment: What if I want to add the $ sign again after summing up the 'Total sales USD'? And just the same, I want to apply it to groupby(['column1', 'column2']).

Comment: my answer should be helpful. Please provide sample data in your next Stack OverFlow question, and if this answers your question then kindly accept as solution with the checkmark next to the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following to sum currency/float data formatted as a `string` and then adjust the formatting back to:

1. String
2. Float

I have commented out option #1, which will return a string, as I suspect the desired result might be option #2 (a float but *formatted with a $ similar to how you would format a float in Excel*). I have also shown what the output looks like if you run option #1 (a string). I have included `print(df_order_sales_date.info())` to show you how although aesthetically the result is the exact same, the data type and the underlying value are actually different`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B'},
 'column2': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'a', 3: 'a'},
 'Total sales USD': {0: '$10.05', 1: '$20.45', 2: '$5.50', 3: '$15.25'}})
df['Total sales USD'] = df['Total sales USD'].str.strip('$').astype(float)
df_order_sales_date = df.groupby(['column1','column2'])['Total sales USD'].sum().reset_index()
# df_order_sales_date['Total sales USD'] = '$' + df_order_sales_date['Total sales USD'].astype(str) #option1
pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format #option2
print(df_order_sales_date.info())
df_order_sales_date

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------           --------------  ----- 
 0   column1          3 non-null      object
 1   column2          3 non-null      object
 2   Total sales USD  3 non-null      float64
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 200.0+ bytes
None

Out[3]: 
  column1 column2 Total sales USD
0       A       a          $10.05
1       A       b          $20.45
2       B       a          $20.75
```

However, if you go with option #1, then that will return:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------           --------------  ----- 
 0   column1          3 non-null      object
 1   column2          3 non-null      object
 2   Total sales USD  3 non-null      object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 200.0+ bytes
None
Out[367]: 
  column1 column2 Total sales USD
0       A       a          $10.05
1       A       b          $20.45
2       B       a          $20.75
```